# How can I stream camera using ffmpeg and send over network using live555

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, live555

I am making a application for streaming webcam. I would like to use ffmpeg to capture camera, ffmpeg as encoder and live555 as server. I know I must implement DeviceSource.cpp in live555 to encapsulate the encoder to receive frame from ffmpeg.So can anyone provide me some tutorial or example about implementing.Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of what you are after here:

https://www.imc-store.com.au/Articles.asp?ID=278

It is a c++ VS2010 project showing how to encode a raw RGB frame using FFMPEG, and then sending that discrete frame onto Live555 to be streamed.

The VS2010 project includes all the library and include files so it should simply be a case of unzipping, running the .sln file in VS2010, compile and run!

Also the VLC source code implements both FFMPEG and Live555, you could take a look at their code for some extra pointers!

Good luck!